# Is PyTest supposed to run all code or just the function being tested?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm writing a python script and am using PyTest to test it. So far I have written one test for one function within the script (it's a mess so I didn't post it). I was under the impression PyTest would only run the function that is being tested. However, when running PyTest all the code in the script is being executed. Is this intended?

Comment: In order to tell you why this behavior is happening, it would be important that you post at least an exampl of what your code looks liek as well as your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the problem is that your tested python script contains instructions at root level. When you import a module, python runs the code.

I've set up a simple example.

unit_under_test.py

```
print("UNIT UNDER TEST")

def function_to_test():
    print("This shall be tested")
    return 42

def function_not_to_test():
    print("This shall NOT be tested")
    return "foobar"

print("END OF FUNCTION DECLARATIONS")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("MAIN")
    print(function_to_test())
    print(function_not_to_test())
```

test_unit.py

```
import pytest
from unit_under_test import function_to_test

def test_function_to_test():
    assert 42 == function_to_test()
```

When I now run pytest, it outputs the following.

```
UNIT UNDER TEST
END OF FUNCTION DECLARATIONS
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/moritzschillinger/dev/python/test/foo/test_stuff
collected 1 item

test_stuff.py .                                                          [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.03s ===============================
```

See how python executed the code of `unit_under_test.py`. It outputs the statements "UNIT UNDER TEST" and "END OF FUNCTION DECLARATIONS".

If you have instructions in your file in order to run your logic, move it into the block under `if __name__ == '__main__':`. This section is only run, when running the python file as `__main__` meaning when you call `python unit_under_test.py`. You can see the statement "MAIN" was not printed in the pytest output.